# Translate routes Laravel with text from database

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I'm using Voyager 1.0. And I have a blog project. I have a problem because I don't know how to translate the routes.

For example

```
   Route::get('projects/{slug}','Admin\ProjectController@project');
```

I know how to translate the slug, but I don't know how can I translate 'projects' without using files. I don't want to use files, because it's a trick here.. The admin can add how many languages he wants, and I'm trying to avoid creation of files..that's why all of my text from entire website is on database.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Wreigh I saw in many multilanguages websites..everything was translated..

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel-localization(https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/blob/master/README.md#translated-routes) package for translated routes.

After all static translated routes you must define dynamic translated routes on bottom of routes file.

If you want to all slugs are translated, you can define main content model like Page and this model maybe has parent and child Page models OR you can create table for slugs which keep all different type content(Polymorphic relationship) slugs with language code unique integrity and provide parent child relations.

After provide multilanguage slugs in site, you can query on this slugs table or main content table.

Your dynamic route only contains parameters like this:

```
   {slug}/{slug_2?}/{slug_3?}
```